# Receiving "Attribute Error:'module' object has no attribute" when running my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3 and the following code is giving me an attribute error.
The code below is where I'm having my issue

```
command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh","wlan","show","profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
```

Error message:

```
Attribute Error:'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Is there anything I can use in the place of this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your code doesn't have enough detail to meaningfully help, please [edit] to include a [mcve] showing what `subprocess` is, where it's being imported from, etc. The error is telling you that the `subprocess` module doesn't have a `run` attribute, so that's where the problem lies

Comment: Assuming you're using Python 3.5+, your problem is you named your script (or some other file in that directory) `subprocess.py`, or named a subdirectory there `subprocess`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess.run()` function only exists in `Python 3.5` and newer.
So upgrade your python version to 3.5 or higher to solve your problem, you can do that by creating a virtual environment with Python 3.8 for example.